# Choose specific access point in a multiple access point WIFI network sharing SSID

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

In my university, there is a big WIFI network which is covered by different access points (antennas) which all share the same SSID.

One of these access point doesn't work: broken or misconfigured. So, when I use Linux I can choose to which access point connect to (I see them all and I simply choose one which works).

My girlfriend, unfortunately has a netbook (Samsung N150) which runs Windows 7 (poor her) but with this OS I'm unable to find any configuration to set it to connect to a specific access point over the various available which all have the same SSID. Usually the network card software has a software to set this advanced features, but not this one (it simply use the Wn configuration tools - doesn't seem to have any advanced configuration software specific to the WIFI driver).

Do you guys know any utility which I can use to specify on Windows 7 to which access point from all those available to connect to?

Comment: I don't think windows seven allows selection by bssid.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/265142/connect-to-wi-fi-access-point-with-specific-mac-address

Comment: how do you do it on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open network sharing center, then click on the picture for your active wireless network it should come up with a window called "set network properties".  At the bottom of the window is a button for "merge or delete network locations".  After you are disconnected from the network, you can delete the bad AP from this list.  It will not connect to that AP again.

Comment: How to do this in Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this in NetSetMan:
http://www.netsetman.com/en/wifi
The software is free for personal use.

Main menu -> Tools > NSM WiFi Management

Choose the AP you'd like to use and connect.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know of a free utility, but from what I've gleaned (no personal experience, so YMMV) [WirelessMon](http://www.passmark.com/products/wirelessmonitor.htm) (USD 24) allows a user to connect to a specific access point within a network containing multiple devices all within a single SSID.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, use WifiInfoView tool, which is freeware and works like a charm: https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/connect-access-point-mac-address.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1083788)