# How can I connect to an Access Point by BSSID instead of ESSID in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Suppose there is a network with several Access Points, all with the same ESSID, but I always want to connect to an specific access point that has a certain BSSID (MAC address), is it possible to do this in Windows?

I tried making this type of connection by using the Native Wifi API, but the Connect function only lets you specify the ESSID not BSSID.

Has anyone found a way to connect to an AP, by specifying its BSSID in Windows?

Comment: Why don't you just avoid connecting to the other access points and mark the access point you do want to connect to as a prefeered connection.

Comment: I'd like to do that, but the Windows Wireless Network Configuration  only lets you mark access points by ESSID (Network Name), I can't tell it to select an AP by BSSID (AP Mac Address).

Comment: Several Access Points (with different BSSID[MAC Address]) near me have the same ESSID(Network Name), since they are part of the same network.

Comment: For some stupid reason, windows sometimes disconnects from the AP with the best Signal and instead connects to one with a worse signal, and my connection gets mega super slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free utility (for home use) [NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/en/wifi-wlan-manager) includes a utility called NSM Wifi Management, which lets you do just that... connect to WiFi AP by BSSID instead of ESSID.

Once installed, choose

> Tools --> NSM Wifi Management

Then choose

> Down Arrow next to Refresh --> In-Depth Refresh.

All APs will be listed, even those with the same ESSID, and you can choose the one you want. It doesn't show you the MAC/BSSID in the search results, but you can try them all one at a time and type

> netsh wlan show interfaces

at the cmd prompt to check when you have the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Did you manage to solve this?
In case it's helpful, I've found a partial solution.

The utility WirelessMon - http://www.passmark.com/products/wirelessmonitor.htm
It allows you to override Windows wifi selection, and explicitly connect to an AP by MAC address.

I had the highly frustrating problem of needing to use a public hotspot network with a portal website, and every time my wifi roaming jumped AP, every ~5 minutes or so owing to two of them being very similar signal strength, I'd have to re-enter my login details.

The downsides of using WirelessMon are, it's only a 30-day trial, and it also tends to screw up the connection itself by constantly scanning in the background.  The best solution I've found is to set its sampling rate to the maximum of 60 seconds, which helps enormously compared to the default of 3.

If anyone knows of a free app that does a similar job, please post about it!

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I will nice answer. +1

Comment: This worked, but since it is not a free tool, I am afraid I cannot accept it as *the* solution.

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco: There is no "the" solution. Windows does not have a capability so you have to use a third party tool. Some wireless cards come with a free one but they are specific to that card and there is no information about the card in the question anyway.

Comment: 44$ LOL LOL LOL LOL

Answer (score 2):

Try Nirsoft WirelessNetView - it's freeware. There's no option to do this without 2nd party software, just for available BSSID's - it can be done via netsh, powershell etc.
If you want to do this in Windows - you must change Wireless Zero configuration.. and it's Windows built in.

Comment: how is it done with netsh or powershell? also do you know of a solution for mac or Android?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Intel adapters with PROSet software [here](https://superuser.com/questions/265142/connect-to-wi-fi-access-point-with-specific-mac-address).

Basically you have to choose your Wi-Fi network from list, select checkbox for using Intel parameters, select "*Mandatory Access Point*" and enter BSSID. (Unfortunately cannot tell exact names because my Windows localization not in english.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WifiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) from https://www.nirsoft.net/

Connect wifi using below step.

[image: Connect Wifi]

---

---

You can also `create a shortcut on desktop`, to connect wifi using `BSSID`.

### [image: wifi shortcut]

Shortcut look like:

[image: shortcut icon]