# How do I choose which router to connect to with the same SSID?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

In my area, there is a big network of around 50 routers with same SSID. My devices automatically connect to the closest and strongest network.

How can I connect to one of those manually which are in the range?

Example:

```
| Router || Network SSID || Strength |
--------------------------------------
| One    || RandomName   || 85%      |
| Two    || RandomName   || 75%      |
| Three  || RandomName   || 65%      |
| Four   || RandomName   || 60%      |
--------------------------------------
```

My device automatically connect to `Router One` because it has the maximum strength. How can I connect to `Router Two` or `Router Three` (or `Four`)?

I need a solution for Linux.

Comment: You're looking to connect to a specific BSSID. We have an existing question for Windows ( http://superuser.com/questions/485517/how-can-i-connect-to-an-access-point-by-bssid-instead-of-essid-in-windows-7), so you can either make this Linux-only or have it closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, IIRC Kubuntu's wireless utility lets you specify a BSSID.

Comment: @Bob, I made the question Linux only, but I don't think that specific question has a good solution already. How can I get the Kubuntu's wireless utility on Ubuntu?

Comment: Same question on AskUbuntu: [wireless - How can I connect to a specific BSSID? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833905/how-can-i-connect-to-a-specific-bssid)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by connecting to the AP manually.

First, it is easiest to turn off network manager, if you are running one:

```
  sudo service network-manager stop
```

Then you need to identify the BSSID  of the AP you wish to join: the command

```
 sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
```

(if you are using *wlan0* as your wireless interface) will produce a lot of output, among which you will find something like:

```
  BSS f8:1a:67:aa:7f:b9 (on wlan0) -- associated
    TSF: 629432841083 usec (7d, 06:50:32)
    freq: 2417
    beacon interval: 100
    capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble SpectrumMgmt ShortSlotTime (0x0531)
    signal: -70.00 dBm
    last seen: 0 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: MySSID_NAME
```

(the output is longer than this). The relevant part is of course *BSS f8:1a:67:aa:7f:b9*.

Next, you will have to free your interface of any previous IP addresses, just in case:

```
  sudo ip link set wlan0 down
  sudo ip addr flush dev wlan0
  sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

Now you specify you want to connect to the specific AP:

```
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid MySSID_NAME ap f8:1a:67:aa:7f:b9
```

where of course *ap* precedes the *BSSID* you just identified.

Now you need to start *wpa_supplicant*,

```
 sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -i wlan0 -B -c FILE_with_WPA_Secrets
```

(if you do not know how to set up the file with your WPA credentials, you may look it up [here for instance](http://www.pantz.org/software/wpa_supplicant/wirelesswpa2andlinux.html); just be careful, where it says *network= {*, it should be *network={* without a space). Lastly,

```
 sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

(the *-v* flag does not work on all Linux distros, I like it because I can monitor what is happening).

EDIT

The instructions above work for a network with WPA security. Fore WEP security, replace the  wpa_supplicant command with:

```
  sudo iwconfig wlan0 key s:Your_WEP_password
```

Remember that the two characters *s:* before your password are necessary.
After this, once again

```
  sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'll try it for sure, but one thing I notice is it says `WPA credentials`, the network I am talking about is on WEP, it will still be the same?

Comment: @AkshatMittal No, it is actually easier. Pls see my edit

Comment: Seems like it ain't working for me, I tried on multiple systems. I always have some sort of error in any one of the steps.

Comment: @AkshatMittal Could you be more specific?

Comment: 1. `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid MySSID_NAME ap f8:1a:67:aa:7f:b9` says "SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation already in progress." but it ain't. I am disconnected.

2. `sudo iwconfig wlan0 key s:Your_WEP_password` says "Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.". Don't know why.

I am disconnected from the network and I have changed ESSID, BSSID, Password at appropriate places.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I get the same error in the same step as Akshat Mittal.  Is there some way to identify what is causing this error?

Comment: Addition: on distributions with `systemctl`, first step should be `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager` .