# How do I pinpoint why wifi access is dropping

Tags: wireless-networking, router, signal

I am in a public building (ie. library) with wifi. I am trying to to pinpoint why a wifi signal keeps dropping...or find a why to work around it. My boss often uses the wifi and recently she has encountered problems with the wifi just dropping off and internet not loading.

I have determined that it is issues with the wifi signal, and not her computer that has caused the problem.

While surfing the internet on a laptop I also had Wifi Analyzer app open on my tablet. Dropped internet page loads coincided with signal drops on the WA app. I then noticed there were two different signals from the router (different MAC addresses) and found a link ([Connect to Wi-Fi access point with specific MAC address](https://superuser.com/questions/265142/connect-to-wi-fi-access-point-with-specific-mac-address)) on how to get her computer to access the slightly slower but much more stable MAC address signal.

I also saw that there were other wifi signals nearby in the same range dropping in and out.

Besides having a dedicated landline....why other things can I do to help troubleshoot this issue? Anything else I can tweak? I'm an enduser and I know there are ton of variables on this problem.

THanks for your help! :)

Comment: Since there are other wi-fi signals nearby that are also dropping randomly are you sure that it is in fact an issue with the wi-fi signal and not something in the computer causing it e.g. possibly a corrupt driver for the wireless network card?  Are other people in the range experiencing the same issues?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of Wi-Fi Analyzer's analysis? Do you see multiple SSIDs?