# How to know which router I am connected to in my Institute Hostel?

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router

My institute provides internet access in the hostels with the help of of various routers installed in the corridors. The problem is when I connect to the Wi-Fi named "IITD WIFI" on my laptop Asus R558UR-DM069D the speed is pathetic(1-5 Mbps) but connecting to IITD WIFI from my Moto G5 the speed is good (30-40 Mbps).

I suspect that the laptop gets connected to an old router rather to the new ones recently installed in the hostel. The  whereas of the smartphone is .

LAPTOP:
WI-FI CONFIG: 802.11 b/g/n

SMARTPHONE:
WIFI CONFIG:802.11 a/b/g/n

Comment: Are you sure that the devices in the corridors are actually routing. They are probably just WAPs.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following from a command prompt:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

Look at the BSSID value.

The BSSID is the MAC address of the specific access point you are connected to. You can use this value to determine which access point you are connected to in a multi-AP deployment.

Comment: May you modify your post to give an explanation to the questioner, because I deleted my post since you answered correctly, while I slipped up. However, If you don't, offer an explanation I will undelete my answer and change it to show the command because mine had offered an explanation.

Comment: Please Edit your answer with more explanation to make the answer clearer

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. the `netsh` command people mentioned would help but let me explain what most probably is actually happening and how to fix it more generally. I found out that new routers use some technology to combine two different frequencies i.e. 2.5Ghz and 5Ghz. It's called mixed mode or mixed modulation. but the problem is that some wifi cards with 802.11n chips can't distinguish the mixed mode and would keep connecting and disconnecting or would have a veey slow bandwith while connected to such networks (mine was acting like a dial-up connection!). What you can do to fix this is either set the router in sperarate bandwith mode which creates two different Access points for the frequencies. Or try connecting to the access point using its BSSID and not it's SSID. you can also check you network card setting to disable any power saving features that might also cause this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the BSSID or Mac Address (unique device specific address) in Command Prompt (as mentioned by Appleoddity in the other Answer):

```
netsh wlan show interface
```

Look at  under the network adapter in which you are using.

If you don't know which mac address that address belongs to, it can be accessed by going to the Master Router and looking at the addresses (don't know the terminology) for the WPA(2)-Enterprise setup. You can also ask your work's IT team or person(s) for which of those addresses. Sometimes the routers may have the MAC address written on them.

If you want to only connect to that BSSID (likely the 'newer' ones as you describe) then, as mentioned on [this post:](https://superuser.com/questions/265142/connect-to-wi-fi-access-point-with-specific-mac-address)

> You can do this with Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software, but this can only be done if you have Intel® Wireless Adapter. If you have Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software you need to:
>
> Right click light bulb icon in system tray -> "Configure Wi-Fi"
>   Right click on wanted network and select "Properties"
>   Write down the wanted BSSID
>   Press "Close"
>   Click "Profiles" -> "Manage Profiles" (Ctrl+R) or click "Profiles..."
>   Select wanted network, and then click "Properties..."
>   Click "Advanced"
>   Select "Mandatory Access Point" and enter custom MAC address (same as BSSID)
>   This worked for me on Dell Latitude E5520. I don't know if there is custom program for all wireless adapters.

Comment: But that shows the adapter's _own_ address, not the currently connected BSSID?

Comment: @grawity, You are right.... Let me fix that. Give me a second